# Security group settings for RDS to trigger Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I'm following this guide to implement the ability for RDS to trigger Lambda: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/PostgreSQL-Lambda.html#PostgreSQL-Lambda-network. A part of the guide is to set a VPC endpoint to the AWS Lambda VPC.

What values should I use for the port security group? To my knowledge, lambda uses HTTP/HTTPS to receive inputs. Is opening ports 80 and 443 enough?

Comment: "Is opening ports 80 and 443 enough?" - try and let us know what did you find.

Comment: It should really only use port 443.

Comment: @Marcin I enabled 80 and 443 and it works. According to https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/aws-lambda-vpc/, it should be port 443

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that lambda listens to port 443.